# header column not aligned with values after show a hidden DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I use grid with DataTables component.

I want to switch between two grid.
the second one is hidden at startup.

when I show the hidden grid, columns headers are not aligned with columns values
like this
[image]

you can see [here](http://live.datatables.net/ilafap/6/edit#javascript,html,live) in live

you can change the showed grid with radio at the top

an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

An idea which correct your display error but which is not really attractive :
The idea is that your display became correct after sorting of a column so you can bypass it by adding `myTable.fnSort([[0, 'asc']]);` (sort first column by ascending order) after your datatable is initialized.

[See here](http://live.datatables.net/ilafap/4/edit#javascript,html,live)

Comment: I don't want to sort my data, I woudl'd like to keep there how there are put in the table

Comment: The trick I suggest is to sort the data (they keep the same ordering as you have in your example) in order to well-display your header

Answer (score 0):

A little more information would be helpful, but your jquery is not formatting your headers. show some more code or format them manually or get jquery to quit being that way. possibly a way to trick jquery would be to have those headers visible the whole time, but have your text font equal to your background and change the font color when it comes time

Comment: I want to switch between two grid. the second one is hidden at startup. I change my example.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery DataTables does not properly align columns and headers when the table is hidden.  Temporarily show the table while applying dataTables to it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Table1 = $('#Table1').dataTable({
    "bSort": false,
    "sScrollY": "400px",
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bPaginate": false
  });

  $('#Table1Container').hide();
  $('#Table2Container').show();

  Table2 = $('#Table2').dataTable({
    "bSort": false,
    "sScrollY": "400px",
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bPaginate": false
  });

  $('#Table2Container').hide();
  $('#Table1Container').show();

  $("#rdTable1").click(function() {
    $('#Table2Container').hide();
    $('#Table1Container').show();
  });

  $("#rdTable2").click(function() {
    $('#Table1Container').hide();
    $('#Table2Container').show();
  });       

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since DataTables 1.10, this issue can be resolved by calling the `columns.adjust()` [method](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()) when you show your table.